# SQL parse string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have SQL column in this format:

```
http://myServer/Lists/myform/DispForm.aspx?ID=6, RAB12EGH234
http://myServer/Lists/myform/DispForm.aspx?ID=5, CBTRR2345
```

I want to get only

```
RAB12EGH234
CBTRR2345
```

I used this:

```
select 
   substring([FormName], charindex(',', ([FormName]), 0), 20) 
from [myDB].[dbo].[FormList]
```

However I get results like:

```
 , RAB12EGH234
 , CBTRR2345
```

I don't want any space, I don't want comma but just the names. How do I edit my query? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skip two extra characters, and use `rtrim()` to remove trailing spaces:

```
rtrim(substring(FormName, charindex(', ', FormName, 0) + 2, 20))
                                               ^^^^^^
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/143f0/2/0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked. In my e.g. above, I put 20 becuase I thought form Name would not be that long. But how do I make sure I get exact formName? no spaces or blanks after exact formName? FormName's length varies.

Comment: You could add `rtrim` to remote spaces after the formname

Comment: will that be same to this:(substring(FormName, charindex(', ', FormName, 0) + 2, LEN(FornName))
?

Comment: I m not comfy with fixed number 20 in my query. So I thought of getting exact length. Is this ok?

Comment: The exact length is fine.  Note that `len()` returns the length without trailing spaces, f.e. `len('  ') = 0`

Comment: Thanks Andomar for your feedback.