# SQL query to parse column and get value for each parsed row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]
Hi,

This is in ref to question posted here:
[Previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16485365/sql-parse-string)

I have a table with Form Name that contains Url and from that Url, I want to take only Form Name.
Like shown in the picture.:

I have created a function that returns the formName

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getFormName](@p_column varchar(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
declare @FormName varchar(max)
set @FormName = (substring(@p_column,charindex(',',@p_column, 0)+2,50))
RETURN rtrim(@FormName);
END;

GO
```

And I could get the FormName by

> select [dbo].getFormName from myTable

This gives me the result in column B in the picture, which returns all Form Names. However I couldn't get the FormName for each record in row by row fashion. The above subquery returns more than 1 value. How can I get formName row by row? I need row by row value for each FormName because that will be my join key with next table.

Please let me know if I m doing it wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you thinking in terms of "row by row"? Why are you putting this in a scalar UDF, which can kill performance in a variety of ways? Why not just `SELECT SUBSTRING(FormNameWithURL, ...) FROM dbo.tablename`?

Comment: I m thinking row by row because formName is the key to join with another table. That's why I need Form Name row by row. If scalar UDF could kill perf., please suggest me how would you doit? TIA.

Comment: By just applying the SUBSTRING inline. If you need to join on that substring, (a) consider a table redesign, or (b) use a derived table/inline view/CTE. SQL works best on sets. When you start thinking "row by row" you're thinking about it wrong. There are exceptions where a cursor-like approach is appropriate, but they are exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (col varchar(100))
INSERT INTO @temp( col )
VALUES 
('http://myServer/Lists/myform/DispForm.aspx?ID=6, RAB12EGH234'),
('http://myServer/Lists/myform/DispForm.aspx?ID=5, CBTRR2345')

SELECT FormNameWithUrl = col, FormName = SUBSTRING(col, 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', col, 0) = 0 
        THEN 0 
        ELSE CHARINDEX(',', col, 0) + 2 
    END, 50)
FROM @temp
```

Returns:

```
FormNameWithUrl                                                 FormName
--------------------------------------------------------------- --------------
http://myServer/Lists/myform/DispForm.aspx?ID=6, RAB12EGH234    RAB12EGH234
http://myServer/Lists/myform/DispForm.aspx?ID=5, CBTRR2345      CBTRR2345
```

Comment: Hi Mike, my fxn also returns the same. What I m concerned about it how to get a Form Name only for each reocrd in a column next to it( as shown in the picture)? This FormName is the key to join with another table with same Form Name. Any idea? Thanks.